# Searching in GridView ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I want to refresh my GridView while i'm writing a text in a textbox. (Searching in the Gridview).

My problem is that i didn't find an event that fires when the textbox content is changing there's only the OnTextChanged.

I tried to make an ajax call and the problem is that i can't use webcontrols in a static method.

Is there any other solution ? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you add a button in the page the program the click event.

Comment: I tried that and it worked but i just want to search when i'm writing text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a function that fires a doPostBack passing in the parameters as the text in the textbox. See below:

```
<input type="text" id="txtBx" onKeyUp="javascript:updateGrid()" />

<script type="text/javascript">
function updateGrid()
{
  var value = $('#txtBx').val();
  __doPostBack('txtBx', value )
}
</script>
```

In your code behind

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string value = this.Request.Params.Get("__EVENTARGUMENT"); // value 
  //Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] this is the same thing as above just written differently
  // Request["__EVENTTARGET"]; // txtBx

  //then you could check the value
  if(value.trim().length > 0)
  {
     //call a method to update the grid view.
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working but it's not really good because after every key pressed the page refresh. I think i'll use a button to search it's more simple and good for me. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: The other way you could of done this is wrapped the gridview in an update panel. and then instead of __doPostBack('id of the update panel', value ). This will cause a partial post back on the update panel. Then you do a updatepanel.update() after the gridview is updated. Anyways. I personally think the button is a easier and better solution.